# Fixed tab+swipe template is not installed in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, templates

Where can I get this template and how do I install it?  Using the Android SDK Manager I've installed all the Tools and all of the 4.2 choices and the Android Support Library.  So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You no more need to install everything manually. You can install a whole Android/Eclipse IDE with everything you need. 
The Template (tab+swipe, and others) are then present.

Download it at : [Link to Eclipse customized for Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

or if you want the new "Android Studio" : [Link to Android Studio (new Google IDE)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to reinstall eclipse, or look up the reason why the `template´ is missing, you could check this:

Creating Swipe Views with Tabs: 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
Download: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/EffectiveNavigation.zip